# TextInputLayout ailgnBaseLine bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I encountered with problem during `TextInputLayout` adding. Because during error showing this layout changes its baseline got such problem. Is there any workaround?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/search_btn">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@id/search_btn"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_input"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/search" />a
```

Problem example https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yue2q.png

Answer (score 0):

It may be because your `TextInputLayout` is on start of `Button`, and you have given layout margin of `20dp`. When a error occurs it again align with the button and the baseline goes up.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/search_btn">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```